# Unable to create a new maven hello-world project

Tags: java, maven

I am looking at few maven tutorial videos and then I ran into this command after installing maven:

```
mvn archetype:create -DgroupId=com.di.maven -DartifactId=hello-world
```

The build fails and throws the following error:

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.3:create 
(default-cli) on project standalone-pom: Unable to parse configuration of mojo 
org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.3:create for parameter #: Abstract 
class or interface 'org.apache.maven.artifact.repository.ArtifactRepository' cannot be 
instantiated -> [Help 1]
```

What is the reason and how can I fix it? I am running as a user in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 166, accepted):

change `create` to `generate`

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.di.maven -DartifactId=hello-world -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DinteractiveMode=false
```

Comment: mvn archetype:create is deprecated in Maven 3.0.5 and beyond

Answer (score 71):

`mvn archetype:create` is deprecated in Maven 3.0.5 and beyond, [as mentioned in the documentation](http://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/create-mojo.html)

Use `mvn archetype:generate` instead:

> `mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-archetype`

This is an interactive command and will ask for values like `groupId`, `artifactId`, `version`, etc. You can also specify these values in the command and choose the non-interactive mode.

Comment: Pity the maven-eclipse-plugin documentation has not been updated to match http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/reactor.html

Comment: Unfortunately a search for "maven simple java project" gives https://maven.apache.org/plugins-archives/maven-archetype-plugin-1.0-alpha-7/examples/simple.html as the top hit, which is from 2008!

Answer (score 8):

```
mvn archetype:generate 
  -DgroupId=com.biswajit.maven 
  -DartifactId=com.biswajit.maven 
  -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart 
  -DinteractiveMode=false
```

Create does not work in maven 3.0.X or beyond. So use generate instead of create

Answer (score -1):

Add

```
    <dependency>
     <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
     <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
     <version>2.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

to your pom file in

```
 {user.home}/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-archetype-plugin/2.3
```