# Unable to create maven based application using maven-archetype-webapp plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, maven

I am new to J2EE development.I am following tutorials shared @ http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsf/jsf_first_application.htm

for creating maven based application. The issue is when i am running the very first command

*mvn archetype:create -DgroupId=com.tutorialspoint.test -DartifactId=helloworld -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-webapp*

I am getting below  error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2
.3:create (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: Unable to parse configuration
 of mojo org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.3:create for paramete
r #: Cannot create instance of interface org.apache.maven.artifact.repository.Ar
tifactRepository: org.apache.maven.artifact.repository.ArtifactRepository.<init>
() -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]

[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit
ch.

[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

[ERROR]

[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:

[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginConfigurationException
```

It is asking to go to the above location but there is not much information available there.Can you please help me out of this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You seem to have the same problem as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29147329/unable-to-create-a-new-maven-hello-world-project).

The answer seem to be that you should use generate instead of create :

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.tutorialspoint.test -DartifactId=helloworld -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-webapp -DinteractiveMode=false
```

Comment: Thanks a lot yannick1976