# Maven: PluginConfigurationException

Tags: java, maven

I am following the [TutorialsPoint's JSF tutorials](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsf/jsf_first_application.htm), I have installed everything correctly but when I want to create a new poroject using `mvn archetype:create -DgroupId=com.east.test -DartifactId=helloworld -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-webapp` command it gives me the following error.

[image]

Any Help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Why didn't you re-run Maven with the -e switch as indicated by the error?

Comment: @BalusC Sir I am not Much familiar with Maven and command line.

Comment: Me neither, I have just read the clue in the error message. I am familiar with English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing `archetype:create` to `archetype:generate` like this:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.east.test -DartifactId=helloworld
    -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-webapp
```

`archetype:create` has been deprecated since Maven version 3.0.5.

By the way, this question appears to be a duplicate of [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29147329/unable-to-create-a-new-maven-hello-world-project).  However, I gave an answer because simply listing the other answer might not make it obvious how to handle the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your nice solution, you know I searched for the PluginConfigurationException but I did not got any results about this exception.